# Using Python subprocess to call a command multiple times

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use Python subprocess to call a command recursively.  To summarize what I am doing, command "info" has multiple sub-commands that does various functions, i.e.

```
info list 
info copy
info share
info run-script -f <script_file to run>
```

The problem is the info run-script command.  On a command terminal, if someone input

> info run-script -f script.sc

Content of script.sc:

```
info list
info copy
```

Then in the code I open a subprocess and call info: `subprocess(['info', 'list'])`, when I do this, the process appeared to be lost and never came back.  Is it because there is already an instance of info running?  Has anyone run into this and have a solution or explanation?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What do you mean by "the process appeared to be lost and never came back"?

Comment: What do you mean "lost and never came back"?  Do you not see output but expect to?  Or does the program run forever?  Did your computer raise an Amber alert?

Comment: You can use multiprocessing… Take a look at this question:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840550/running-script-multiple-times-simultaniously-in-python-2-7

Comment: There are many ways to solve this issue

1) see if your commands return result in stderr/stdout...
2) if your command goes to forever, try executing the command in background to see whats going on
3) is info located to right binary?
4) i would put timeout for the process by signaling 
5) periodically print result of your command
6) use multiprocessing to solve

Comment: As long as the "script file" can only contain more commands for this program, is there a reason you can't parse it and run them individually inside the same process? If it can contain commands not for your program (like a full on bash script or something), I think your program is probably trying to do too much.

Comment: "lost and never came back" means that the process never returns.  When I tried to do ps -ef | grep info, I can see 2 processes running.  If I kill the child process, then the system exits cleanly.

Comment: "lost and never came back" means that the child process never returns.  When I tried to do ps -ef | grep info, I can see 2 info processes running.  If I kill the child process, then the system exits cleanly.  Initially I tried to print the return result to sterr/stdout and have a timeout and the child process hangs and never came back.  subproc = subprocess.Popen(['info', 'list'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)   (out, err) = subproc.communicate().  Then I made stdout and stderr set to None, with this the system exits cleanly.  However I need to collect the output.